# How to do gradient transitions using slimdx?

Tags: slimdx

I am doing gray scale transitions between different images and have an idea that i can do it by doing some blending but can any body please help me how to actually implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done language-agnostically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697356/how-to-transition-between-two-images-using-a-grayscale-transition-map)

It seems it can be done in a pixel shader, but speed concerns require precomputing blending ratios.